# Bind ListView Items to editable Combobox selected value

Tags: c#, listview, combobox

I have a ListView and a ComboBox. Both of them bind to the same List filled with database items.

1. I want the ListView items reflect the selected items in the ComboBox (i.e. when the user selects "Name0" I want the listview to display only the Name0 row). It works if I select the items from the dropdown list but when I type the text in the combobox (being it editable) it raises a null exception if the text doesn't match the combo items content (i.e. if I type "Name01" or if I delete the text using backslash). I tried to change the search string to the Text property of the ComboBox but this way the list is updated only the second time I select the item (if I select "Name0" nothing happens, if I then select "Name1" the list dispays "Name0" row instead).
2. Additionally I would like to search the text in the combo for substrings also (i.e. if I type "4" I would like the listview to show the "Name4" row) but it only searches text from the first letter of the word.To achieve this I tried to use Table.Select instead of String.Contains but nothing changes. 
   Any help is much apreciated.
   Hope my question is clear enough (I am an amateur programmer).

Here is my code:

```
namespace LVCombo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();
        public static List<Persons> MyList = new List<Persons>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataTable MyDataTable = MyDataSet.Tables.Add("MyDataTable");
            MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
            AddData(MyDataTable);
            CreateList();
            MyListView.ItemsSource = MyList;
            MyCombo.ItemsSource = MyList;
        }`

        private void AddData(DataTable table)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                row["Name"] = "Name" + i.ToString();
                row["Age"] = "4" + i.ToString();
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        public class Persons
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }

        private void CreateList()
        {
            foreach(DataRow row in MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                MyList.Add(new Persons() { Name=row["Name"].ToString(), Age= (int)row["Age"]});
            }
        }

        private void MyCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
            List<Persons> SelectedPersons = new List<Persons>();
            MyListView.ItemsSource = SelectedPersons;
          //  string person = combo.SelectedValue.ToString().ToLower();
               string person = combo.Text.ToLower();

            //Table.Select version
            DataRow[] FilteredRows = MyDataSet.Tables[0].Select(string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", MyDataSet.Tables[0].Columns["Name"], person));
            for(int i = 0; i < FilteredRows.Length; i++)
            {
                SelectedPersons.Add(new Persons()
                {
                    Name = FilteredRows[i]["Name"].ToString(),
                    Age = (int)FilteredRows[i]["Age"]
                });
                MyListView.ItemsSource = SelectedPersons;
            }


            //String.Contains version

         /*   foreach (DataRow row in MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (row["Name"].ToString().ToLower().Contains(person))
                {
                    SelectedPersons.Add(new Persons() { Name = row["Name"].ToString(), Age = (int)row["Age"] });
                }
            MyListView.ItemsSource = SelectedPersons;*/

        }
    }
}
```

and my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="LVCombo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LVCombo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView Name="MyListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Margin="10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ComboBox Name="MyCombo" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" IsEditable="True" 
                  Height="22" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="MyCombo_SelectionChanged"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself, I am posting an answer just in case someone else encounters the same problem.
I should have used the TextBoxBase.TextChanged event instead of Combobox.SelectionChanged one. Doing that solves both problems.

```
<ComboBox Name="MyCombo" IsEditable="True" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="MyCombo_TextChanged"
```